# swift activityIndicator stops animation automatically

Tags: ios, swift, animation, tableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a tableview with multiple tableviewcells. Each cell has an UIActivityIndicatorView which is triggered based on the state:

```
private func stateDidChange(duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    switch self.state {
    case .Failed:
       self.testingIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.animateWithColor(self.redColor.CGColor)
        break
    case .Success:
        self.testingIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.animateWithColor(self.greenColor.CGColor)
        break
    case .Testing:
        self.testingIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.animateWithColor(self.greyColor.CGColor)
        break
    case .Unknown:
        self.testingIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.animateWithColor(self.greyColor.CGColor)
        break
    }
}
private func animateWithColor(color: CGColor) {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(self.duration)
    CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut))
    self.shapeLayer.strokeColor = color
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

The second function animates the strokeColor of a circle around the indicator.
I'm using this observer to observe a state change:

```
 var state: TestStepModel.State {
        didSet {
                self.stateDidChange(self.duration)
        }
 }
```

Everything works as expected so far, but I update every cell if only one changed.
So I added this code to the observer:

```
 var state: TestStepModel.State {
        didSet {
            if state != oldValue {
                self.stateDidChange(self.duration)
            }
        }
 }
```

Suddenly, EVERY activity indicator in EVERY cell stops animating, as soon as the first state changes.
What is even worse is, that I can uncomment every .stopAnimating() call like this:

```
switch self.state {
    case .Failed:
        //self.testingIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.animateWithColor(self.redColor.CGColor)
        break
    case .Success:
        //self.testingIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.animateWithColor(self.greenColor.CGColor)
        break
    case .Testing:
        self.testingIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.animateWithColor(self.greyColor.CGColor)
        break
    case .Unknown:
        //self.testingIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.animateWithColor(self.greyColor.CGColor)
        break
    }
```

and it still stops animating after the first state has changed. And yes there is no other stopAnimating() call expect those three (searched in the whole project).

So yeah of course this is a really weird and specific problem, but maybe someone has a clue on how to solve it or faced a similar problem...
The activity indicator should only stop and hide when I call .stopAnimating(), but it stops when i trigger a state change.

Comment: Are you reloading the table in some place? Are you resetting the cell UI when the cell is reused?

Comment: @Sulthan That might actually be the only possibility for the problem. I'm going to look into that...

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Comment: @AndreiS yes I did but i cant remember it. Do you still need an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, all i did is stopped reloading the collectionview. Let me know if that helped else I can share the code snippets too.